# String.replace() is replacing one of two strings only

Tags: java, string

I have this line of text:

> number of troops the united states has stationed in south viet nam as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany .

And what i'm trying to do is check the *line of text* for any words that may have a meaning when **combined**.

For example: replace the `viet nam` String with the correct word `vietnam`.

---

I wrote this function:

```
private String correctLine(ArrayList<String> newWords, String line) {
    line = line.toLowerCase();
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < newWords.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
            if(newWords.get(i).toLowerCase().equals(words[j].concat((j + 1 == words.length)?"":words[j+1]))){
                line = line.replace(words[j].toLowerCase(), newWords.get(i).toLowerCase());
                line = line.replace(words[j+1].toLowerCase(), "");
            }
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

What this function do is it takes a List of words `newWords` that will be replaced in the text, and the target line of text `line`.

**The problem:**

When the `if` condition is met:

`vietnam` is equal to `words[j]` (viet) & `words[j+1]` (nam)

I replace the `line` twice:

- replace `viet` with `vietnam`.
- replace `nam` with  .

But what happens is only one of them is being replaced, while the other is ignored.

1. If i comment the first `replace` the result is:

   `number of troops the united states has stationed in south viet  as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany .`
2. If i comment the second `replace` the result is:

   `number of troops the united states has stationed in south vietnam nam as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany .`

Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: I believe that you need to run this in a debugger or use print statements to check the values of your variables. Printing the values of line and the replacement values will do. I would also think that the value ``words[j+1]`` should eventually cause an OutOfBoundsException when j == words.length - 1. And the entire inner for-loop will not do what you think it will, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think very hard about the two statements about what you replace, if you replace `viet` with `vietnam` and then replace `nam` with nothing then you obviously will replace the `nam` of the **just replaced** `vietnam` again. Resulting in `viet nam` -> `vietnam nam` -> `viet nam`.

You might get away by simply switching the two statements around:

```
line = line.replace(words[j+1].toLowerCase(), "");
line = line.replace(words[j].toLowerCase(), newWords.get(i).toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 2):

luk2302 is correct, although you will end up with two consecutive spaces with that approach which has to be addressed as well. Might I suggest another approach which is simpler and more flexible?

```
    Map<String, String> replace = new HashMap<>();
    replace.put("viet nam", "vietnam");
    
    String line = "number of troops the united states has stationed in south viet nam as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany .";
    
    for (String key : replace.keySet()) {
        line = line.replaceAll(key, replace.get(key));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the two `replace`.

Below code is tested and working fine.

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        
        String line = "in south viet nam as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany";
        ArrayList<String> newWords = new ArrayList<>();
        newWords.add("vietnam");
        newWords.add("India");
        
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < newWords.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                if(newWords.get(i).toLowerCase().equals(words[j].concat((j + 1 == words.length)?"":words[j+1]))){
                    line = line.replace((words[j] + " " + words[j+1]), newWords.get(i).toLowerCase());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
in south vietnam as compared with the number of troops it has stationed in west germany
```